# HQL query. Inner join entity without mapping relation

Tags: hql

I have three entities. Let's say Apple, Banana and Cactus. Apple have some properties(colour, flavour...) and a many-to-one relation with Banana by Banana_id. Banana have some properties(....) and a many-to-one relation to Apple by Apple_id. Entity Cactus - some properties, many-to-one relation to Banana by Banana_id.

So, if I begin writing the query needed...

```
SELECT A.banana
FROM Apple A

WHERE A.someAppleProperty = something
AND A.someOtherAppleProperty > something else
AND A.banana.someBananaProperty = something
```

How to write an inner join, or use some other approach, so I can include property from Cactus entity in the WHERE clause

Apologise for the way I describe my problem, if someone understand what I've got in mind and help it'll be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.banana
FROM Apple A, Cactus C
WHERE A.someAppleProperty = something
AND A.someOtherAppleProperty > something else
AND A.banana.someBananaProperty = something
AND C.foo = 'bar'
AND C.banana = A.banana
```

Comment: Thanks, for reply. I've tried it, works fine for now.